# Proof a sorting algorithm is incorrect

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was given an algorithm as below and my aim is to prove its incorrectness. The thing is that it woud be too obvious to use just counter-example, that is why I was looking for a more formal approach. I have thought the **proof by induction**, but in the past I had use it only to prove the correctness of an algorithm and I can't really figure out the opposite way.

```
GoodSort(A, left, right)
{
 if (A[left] > A[right]) 
   swap(A[left], A[right]);
 if (left+1 >= right) 
   return;
 pivot = floor((right-left+1)/3);
 GoodSort(A, left, right-pivot);
 GoodSort(A, left+pivot, right); 
}
```

Comment: A counter example is a proof. "Obvious" is not a negative thing when it comes to proofs.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for a proof rather than a solution to a programming problem.

Comment: Of course it's not negative but I thought that  a formal way to solve such a problem would be reachable

Comment: The utility of a proof is the number of readers who will accept it.  Write proofs that are useful, not proofs that make you look smart.  A simple counter-example is the best proof, when it's available.

Comment: A counter-example is a formal proof. There are no proofs "more formal" than that, only ones that are just as formal and possibly more complicated and error-prone.

Comment: The benefit of a formal approach comes in cases in which you do not know a priori that an assertion is false or a counterexample is hard to come by with.

Comment: If you have a counter example, you may be able to generalize it, which may be closer to what you're looking for. From there, you can possibly demonstrate the general form of fault in this algorithm.

Comment: Another option is to prove a weaker property that implies the algorithm's incorrectness. The advantage is that no reasoning over arbitrary inputs is needed. In the GoodSort algorithm it is straightforward to see that, apart from the very last element, none of the `floor(length/3)` last elements of the original array ever moves into one of the first `floor(length/3)` positions for 'sufficiently long' arrays ( length >= 6 ). Which means the sort is incorrect if said elements happen to comprise the globally smallest element.

Comment: I'm going to second "a counterexample is a proof". Students often have a giant misimpression that proofs need to be big and complicated things done in some official matter. Really, they just have to be logically airtight demonstrations. Back when I was teaching linear algebra I wrote up https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_uwl3WDZk_BxNOUL7W0FiPMMxdmi7w4OoP4prUcIs2s/edit?usp=sharing to help people learn to do proofs. It may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any purpose but a class assignment where it's forbidden, a proof by counterexample, e.g. [3,2,4,0,1,4], would be ideal. As some commenters said, clarity and simplicity is desirable.

Assuming this is a class assignment and you need to categorize the set of inputs (or a set of inputs) where this will fail that's broader than a single counterexample, take some minimal input that fails, and analyze why it fails, then generalize that.

Answer (score 1):

An algorithm can either be correct or incorrect, if you are having a hard time finding ways to prove its incorrectness you can rather try to prove its correctness. If you reach a nonsense you can then conclude that the algorithm is incorrect. This method is called **Reductio ad Absurdum**

Comment: That's also called a proof by contradiction